# How to handle parents browser windows page features from child windows close in JS

Tags: javascript

I open a page in browser. There is a link where I click, its fade the page, by putting a layer in the Z-index. At the mean time another Pop up window is also open.
When I close the pop up window, the browser remain still faded. 
I can’t disable the z-index layer that I put in the parents window. 
Enter code is done in Java Script.

Comment: how are you change the z-index, please include some code to take as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

I believe want you want to do is something like this.  On your parent window/page:

```
var fadeIn = function fadeIn() {
    // Code to remove added layer
};
```

And on your child/popup window/page:

```
window.onunload = function () {
    window.opener.fadeIn();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any JavaScript that resides in the parent page can be called by the child.  In your child popup your "close' button click event should have an event similar to this:

```
function closePopup()
{ 
    parent.FadeOut();  // Where fadeOut() is a JS function on the parent page
}


//In the Parent Page
function fadeOut()
{
   document.getElementById('myLayer').zindex = 0; //Or similar 
}
```

Comment: Was this what you were looking for in terms of a workable solution?